# Magento2 admin login not redirecting to dashboard page

Tags: magento2, login, admin-panel, magento-upgrade

after upgrade from magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.4, Admin login not redirecting to dashboard page.no errors coming but it just stays in login page.

[image: redirect back to login page]

Can anyone let me know what could be issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing same problem on magento 2.4.3. 1st changed the value of 0 but it take to much time and also reduced server resource usage. then I update my php memory limit, max_input_time and max_input_vars  maximum values then run this command.

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000
```

Answer (score 5):

bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000

this solution worked for me.

Comment: This is documented as a known issue in 2.4.4 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35297

Answer (score 1):

This is Adobe Commerce 2.4.4 core bug. If you want to use 0 value you need to apply patch to `vendor/magento/framework`

```
diff --git a/Session/SaveHandler.php b/Session/SaveHandler.php
--- a/Session/SaveHandler.php
+++ b/Session/SaveHandler.php
@@ -126,7 +126,7 @@ class SaveHandler implements SaveHandlerInterface
         $sessionMaxSize = $this->sessionMaxSizeConfig->getSessionMaxSize();
         $sessionSize = strlen($sessionData);
 
-        if ($sessionSize !== null && $sessionMaxSize < $sessionSize) {
+        if ($sessionMaxSize !== null && $sessionMaxSize < $sessionSize) {
             $sessionData = '';
             if ($this->appState->getAreaCode() === Area::AREA_FRONTEND) {
                 $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but it didn't work for me when I had NO VALUE set. Instead I applied the `bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000` command and that worked